# How to create Current Year Earnings in Odoo 10 and close fiscal year?

Tags: odoo

I am trying to close a fiscal year in Odoo 10. In the document, it's saying create a `Current Year Earnings` before setting the `Lock Date`. What will be the value for it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

1. I took Balance sheet period of 01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018
2. Fetch the profit and loss amount, say −9126.21
3. Created a journal entry with following lines
4. Debited to 111300 Reserve and Profit/Loss Account (9126.21)
5. Credited to 999999 Undistributed Profits/Losses (9,126.21)
6. Choose date as 01-01-2019
7. Save and Posted
8. And set lock date as 31-12-2018

Am not sure about the above steps, if am wrong correct me.